# Example code on how to use tf.contrib.rnn.NASCell in Tensoflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

After watching Tensorflow 2017 Summit videos I got curious about this new object that uses Reinforcement Learning in order to find an Optimal NN Architecture.
I'm new to Python and to Tensorflow. Just going through beginners tutorials. 
Can anyone show me in code example how exactly this NASCell works?

[NASCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/NASCell)

Comment: It conforms to the same interface as other RNNCells, and should be a drop-in replacement for cells in the [RNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent).

Comment: Unless I miss something, I don't think it's the same. In the RNN from tutorial we train RNN for text prediction based on labelled data in the PTB dataset and NASCell doesnt have any labelled dataset to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

You can see example of tf.contrib.rnn.NASCell in this repo

[nascell-automl](https://github.com/wallarm/nascell-automl)